# Open Graph meta tags not working

Tags: facebook, laravel, laravel-4, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to implement OG meta tags into my web site, but when I visit facebook debuger tool it reports that og:type is missing although it's not missing.

This is the link for one of my posts: http://objavi.net/posts/9

Don't know if it matters, but I use Laravel 4.

This is the code I use:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ asset('uploads/' . $post->img) }}">
<meta property="og:title" content="{{ $post->title }}">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ Request::url() }}">
```

this code is yielded into main layout.

Answer (score 0):

> "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

The page with the tags must be available in public, or Facebook will not be able to parse them.

Edit: It is working now, but the debugger still does not parse the tags. Try putting the meta tags before any CSS or JavaScript code.

Comment: How to do that in Laravel. Laravel needs to render view, then rendered view (plain html) is public

Comment: did you change something? i can see the website now - although it still does not work in the debugger. laravel should not be a problem, it is server side anyway.

Comment: Yes, I used this package: http://packalyst.com/packages/package/chriskonnertz/open-graph but it produces same meta tags which I made manually

Comment: yeah, the meta tags actually look fine to me...try my suggestion in the edit of the answer.

Comment: I did but it's still the same. I'm also using addthis plugin if it matters

Comment: Strange but when you visit main page: http://objavi.net/ then everything is ok, although there is no og meta tags in main page

Comment: can you put meta tags on your main page for testing? btw, you should add open graph tags on your main page anyway.

Comment: I did, it's not working 100% but it's far better then in posts page